# best approach to search from pivot table using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivottable.js

Searching from  pivot table using laravel.

Here is my table structure:

```
Product
id
name

Categories
id
name

product_category (Pivot table)

id
category_id
product_id

//products can have multiple categories
```

Product model:

```
public function categories(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_category');
}
```

What is the best way to search all products by category id?
Currently I am doing this way, and it seems not an efficient way:

```
//Controller
$categories = product_category::where('category_id',1)->get();
```

Now I have to loop through categories and then get Products and pass it to views? Any idea how to do this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this you could use the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$categoryId = 1;

$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($categoryId) {
    $query->where('categories.id', $categoryId);
})->get();
```

The above will return all products that are in the Category where the id is equal to `$categoryId`.

Comment: I think in this specific case it should be: `$query->where('category_product.category_id', $categoryId);`. Otherwise you'll get `ambiguous column name` exception since there's an id colum on the pivot.

Comment: Thank you for nice suggestion,i will try to implement this @Amade

Answer (score 1):

You can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) products for a given category. Try:

```
$category = Category::with('products')->where('category_id',1)->find(1);
```

When you do this, only 2 database queries will be executed: one for loading the category, and one for loading related products.

Then in your Blade view you can do:

```
@foreach($category->products as $product
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this inside your method in controller..this only works when $request->$query(search) have value .then here we use wereHas for get the relationship of model and with->() using for get pivot table values

```
->when($request->query('search'), function ($query)use($request) {

   $q= $request->query('search');

   return $query->whereHas('relation name', function (Builder $query) use ($q) {
                  
   $query->with('pivot table name.column name')  

  ->where('pivot table name.column name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
     });})
```

Comment: Could you please break down the code with some explanation?