# How can I query a pivot table value using Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models and a pivot table:

`Teacher`
`Class`

The pivot table is `class_teacher`. I am running a dynamic query where I can receive an array of class IDs and I want to see which teachers are assigned to them.

A class can have many teachers and a teacher can be in many classes.

What is the best way of querying this with query builder?

So far I have run code using a `whereHas` modifier to pull in the relationship and then used `whereIn` to see if the values are present. Some code is below for example:

```php
return $builder->whereHas('classes', function ($query) use ($value) {
            $query->whereIn('class_teacher.class_id', $value);
        });
```

This doesn't trigger errors but it doesn't return any results when some should show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best approach to search from pivot table using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230841/best-approach-to-search-from-pivot-table-using-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your relationships on the model, and then you won't need to use the query builder for this simple case.

So for example in your `Class` model add this:

```
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
// $values should be an array of class ids
$classes = Class::whereIn('id', $values)->with('teachers')->get();
```

Iterating over each class will give you teachers collection assigned to that class.
Another thing is that Class is reserved word in PHP so I am not sure you can use it like that.